# How does someone check for malware in his machine's firmware?

Tags: malware, firmware, uefi

We've all probably heard of firmware rootkits and other malware by now.

But how do you check if your firmware is infected?

And if you have been infected, how do you get rid of it?

Comment: Is your question about firmware (rootkit,...) or hardware (hardware trojans, backdoors)?  The two things are pretty different.

Comment: Firmware rootkits.

Comment: Depending on the firmware infected, it can be made completely invisible to the OS. (Look into the BluePill rootkit by Rutkowska and the Memory Sinkhole by Domas).

Comment: You can verify the signature of firmware to verify if it has been tampered with. Intel also provides a utility for ordinary users which checks the integrity of your firmware.

Comment: @defalt ...assuming the signature checking mechanism isn't compromised, which can happen with SMM exploits and firmware backdoors.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/chipsec/chipsec

Answer (score 1):

You either need to compare the binary stored in the device with a known safe copy (either by checking a signature or comparing for byte equality with a copy provided by the vendor) or look for symptoms. Both of these are easier said than done.

If comparing a binary how do you get a copy from the device? If by requesting it via some kind of API the firmware offers how do you know the firmware is actually returning itself? Some devices will offer hardware mechanisms to dump rom contents - although attaching a JTAG isn't exactly convenient / easy to perform on a regular basis.

Symptom detection is similar to normal software based malware. Unusual behavior, network traffic etc. The difficulty of this depends on the malware itself.

In theory something well written enough on devices where the firmware controls all IO mechanisms could be impossible to identify until it decides to be malicious - and for all you know this could be triggered remotely.